# Backup Git repo on external hard drive with a sync software

Tags: git, file, backup

I have about 20 or so git repositories on my local drive that I want to backup to my external hard drive. I use FreeFileSync to mirror my local drive on the external. I don't want to just copy my git repo over there, since any changes to the local files will be confusing for the mirroring software.

From what I have read, there are a few options (git bundle, zipping, cloning a bare repo) but I'm not sure what the best method would be for my case. When I plug in my external and get it to do a backup, is there a simple script that can grab all my repos, zip or bundle them, and then move them to the external drive?

Looking for general advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git bundle is the recommended method if you understand that it would *not* include untracked or work in progress files (only existing commits).
Plus it supports incremental backups.

zip is the recommended medthod if you want to grab *everything*.

In that regard, a *simple* script would be one zipping one folder (which would then includes all your Git repositories), assuming your repos are not too big.

You could [configure your USB Key to "autorun"](https://www.howtogeek.com/326049/how-to-auto-run-windows-programs-when-you-plug-in-a-usb-drive/) a program doing just that.

Comment: Thanks, those are helpful ideas. My collection of scripts is about 600 MB at the moment; would that be too big to zip?

Comment: @teepee If those scripts are text-based (no binary), then no. It should be small enough.